# (Game Boy Advance) Program begins at 0x00000000 instead of 0x08000000. How to tell gcc to compile to a specific address?

Tags: c, batch-file, makefile, embedded, game-boy-advance

I've got DevKitPro working on Game Boy Advance, but I've run into a few problems. The biggest one I see is that my code is assembled at `0x00000000` instead of the normal `0x08000000` for ROM cartridges. My understanding is that C compilers don't use an `.org` directive to create the code at a specified memory location; rather the linker is supposed to take care of all that for me. But it seems to be placing the code at the "wrong" address. The game will run correctly, but I imagine this is because it's running on an emulator and the emulator doesn't care that it's located somewhere it shouldn't be. How do I get the code to be "assembled" at `0x08000000`?

I'm new to the concept of makefiles, compilers, linkers, etc. so I probably have everything set up very poorly. I'll show my makefile, batch script that runs the makefile, and the C code that's being compiled. I've also included the objdump in case that's relevant.

C code:

```
// LIBGBA HEADERS
#include <gba_console.h>
#include <gba_video.h>
#include <gba_interrupt.h>
#include <gba_systemcalls.h>
#include <gba_input.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// GAME-SPECIFIC INCLUDES
#include "M:\SrcGBA\PaintBoyAdvance\include\bitmap.h"   
#include "M:\SrcGBA\PaintBoyAdvance\include\bitmap.c"   //BITMAP SCREEN FUNCTIONS

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Program entry point
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(void) {
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    // the vblank interrupt must be enabled for VBlankIntrWait() to work 
    // since the default dispatcher handles the bios flags no vblank handler
    // is required
    irqInit();
    irqEnable(IRQ_VBLANK);
    

    // consoleDemoInit();
    REG_DISPCNT = 0x1403;


    while (1) {
        VBlankIntrWait();
    }
}
```

Batch script:

```
@echo off
set path=C:\devkitPro\;%path%
cd M:\SrcGBA\PaintBoyAdvance
make
if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" goto Abandon

C:\devkitPro\devkitARM\bin\arm-none-eabi-objdump -h M:\SrcGBA\PaintBoyAdvance\build\paintboyadvance.o

C:\Users\puppy\Documents\VisualBoyAdvance\visualboyadvance-m.exe M:\SrcGBA\PaintBoyAdvance\PaintBoyAdvance.gba
:Abandon

exit
```

Makefile:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.SUFFIXES:
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ifeq ($(strip $(DEVKITARM)),)
$(error "Please set DEVKITARM in your environment. export DEVKITARM=<path to>devkitARM")
endif

include $(DEVKITARM)/gba_rules

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TARGET is the name of the output
# BUILD is the directory where object files & intermediate files will be placed
# SOURCES is a list of directories containing source code
# INCLUDES is a list of directories containing extra header files
# DATA is a list of directories containing binary data
# GRAPHICS is a list of directories containing files to be processed by grit
#
# All directories are specified relative to the project directory where
# the makefile is found
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TARGET      := $(notdir $(CURDIR))
BUILD       := build
SOURCES     := source
INCLUDES    := include
DATA        := data
MUSIC       :=

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# options for code generation
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ARCH    :=  -mthumb -mthumb-interwork
SPECS   :=  -specs=gba.specs

CFLAGS  :=  -g -Wall -O2\
        -mcpu=arm7tdmi -mtune=arm7tdmi\
        -ffreestanding \
        $(ARCH)

CFLAGS  :=  $(INCLUDE)

CXXFLAGS    :=  $(CFLAGS) -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions 

ASFLAGS :=  -g $(ARCH)
LDFLAGS =   -g $(ARCH) $(INCLUDE) -Wl,-Map,$(notdir $@.map)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# any extra libraries we wish to link with the project
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIBS    := -lmm -lgba


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# list of directories containing libraries, this must be the top level containing
# include and lib
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIBDIRS :=  $(LIBGBA)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# no real need to edit anything past this point unless you need to add additional
# rules for different file extensions
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


ifneq ($(BUILD),$(notdir $(CURDIR)))
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export OUTPUT   :=  $(CURDIR)/$(TARGET)

export VPATH    :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(CURDIR)/$(dir)) \
            $(foreach dir,$(DATA),$(CURDIR)/$(dir)) \
            $(foreach dir,$(GRAPHICS),$(CURDIR)/$(dir))

export DEPSDIR  :=  $(CURDIR)/$(BUILD)

CFILES      :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c)))
CPPFILES    :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp)))
SFILES      :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.s)))
BINFILES    :=  $(foreach dir,$(DATA),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.*)))

ifneq ($(strip $(MUSIC)),)
    export AUDIOFILES   :=  $(foreach dir,$(notdir $(wildcard $(MUSIC)/*.*)),$(CURDIR)/$(MUSIC)/$(dir))
    BINFILES += soundbank.bin
endif

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# use CXX for linking C++ projects, CC for standard C
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ifeq ($(strip $(CPPFILES)),)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    export LD   :=  $(CC)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
else
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    export LD   :=  $(CXX)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
endif
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export OFILES_BIN := $(addsuffix .o,$(BINFILES))

export OFILES_SOURCES := $(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o) $(CFILES:.c=.o) $(SFILES:.s=.o)

export OFILES := $(OFILES_BIN) $(OFILES_SOURCES)

export HFILES := $(addsuffix .h,$(subst .,_,$(BINFILES)))

export INCLUDE  :=  $(foreach dir,$(INCLUDES),-iquote $(CURDIR)/$(dir)) \
                    $(foreach dir,$(LIBDIRS),-I$(dir)/include) \
                    -I$(CURDIR)/$(BUILD)

export LIBPATHS :=  $(foreach dir,$(LIBDIRS),-L$(dir)/lib)

.PHONY: $(BUILD) clean

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$(BUILD):
    @[ -d $@ ] || mkdir -p $@
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(BUILD) -f $(CURDIR)/Makefile

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
clean:
    @echo clean ...
    @rm -fr $(BUILD) $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).gba


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
else

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# main targets
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$(OUTPUT).gba   :   $(OUTPUT).elf

$(OUTPUT).elf   :   $(OFILES)

$(OFILES_SOURCES) : $(HFILES)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The bin2o rule should be copied and modified
# for each extension used in the data directories
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# rule to build soundbank from music files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
soundbank.bin soundbank.h : $(AUDIOFILES)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @mmutil $^ -osoundbank.bin -hsoundbank.h

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This rule links in binary data with the .bin extension
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%.bin.o %_bin.h :   %.bin
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    @$(bin2o)


-include $(DEPSDIR)/*.d
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
endif
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Output of object dump:

```
M:\SrcGBA\PaintBoyAdvance\build\paintboyadvance.o:     file format elf32-littlearm

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000268  00000000  00000000  00000034  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000000  00000000  00000000  0000029c  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          00000000  00000000  00000000  0000029c  2**0
                  ALLOC
  3 .comment      00000024  00000000  00000000  0000029c  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
  4 .ARM.attributes 0000002a  00000000  00000000  000002c0  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
```

EDIT: As requested here is the output of the batch file:

```
\SrcGBA\PaintBoyAdvance\compile.bat paintboyadvance.c M:\SrcGBA\PaintBoyAdvance\source nopause
Process started >>>
paintboyadvance.c
linking cartridge
built ... PaintBoyAdvance.gba
ROM fixed!

M:\SrcGBA\PaintBoyAdvance\build\paintboyadvance.o:     file format elf32-littlearm

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000280  00000000  00000000  00000034  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000000  00000000  00000000  000002b4  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          00000000  00000000  00000000  000002b4  2**0
                  ALLOC
  3 .comment      00000024  00000000  00000000  000002b4  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
  4 .ARM.attributes 0000002a  00000000  00000000  000002d8  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
```

Comment: You need to add as a parameter your **linker script**

Comment: @0___________ And that would be ```arm-none-eabi-ld```, correct? I'm not sure where to put it.

Comment: you can call it as you want

Comment: .ld is a common extension for linker scripts. I don't know which one your specific tool chain uses. gcc-like environments will often have such a file "foo.ld" where you find stuff along the lines of this: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_chapter/ld_3.html  `.text` is where the code goes.

Comment: You are looking at the unlinked object module. The linker will allocate the code at the correct location, given that you use a correct linker script. Most compiler provide that already. Just follow its tutorial.

Comment: @thebusybee then why does the VisualBoyAdvance disassembly show the code at ```0x00000000```? If I write in assembly and use the ```.org``` directive the code goes where I want it.

Comment: Well, there seems to be a lack of knowledge how compilers, assemblers, and linkers are working. The best way is, you look for a resource that goes into details, but we can try this in the very shortest form here.

Comment: For this, I need your cooperation. Please make sure that your C source file is newer than any binary file produced from it. Do you have an assembly source, too? Great, do this to it, too. It can be as simple as adding some whitespace and saving. -- Then call your batch, and then **[edit] your question and add all the commands that are shown.** (Copy the output in the shell windows verbatim as text, no screenshots, please!) Here I expect calls of compiler, assembler and linker. When done, I'm going to ask you for next steps.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to use a linker script.  I will just post a complete working example.

startup.s

```
.cpu arm7tdmi
.code 32

rom_start:
    b ram_start
    .space 0xA0-0x04,0

    .space 0xC0-0xA0,0

ram_start:
    b _start
    .space 0xE0-0xC4,0

_start:
    ldr sp,=0x03008000
    bl notmain
hang:
    b hang

.globl PUT16
PUT16:
    strh r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.globl GET16
GET16:
    ldrh r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr
```

notmain.c

```
extern void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
extern unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
extern void PUT16 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
extern unsigned int GET16 ( unsigned int );

#define DISPCNT 0x04000000
#define BG0CNT  0x04000008

#define PMEM 0x05000000
#define TMEM 0x06000000
#define VMEM 0x06008000

//#define TWIDE 32
//#define THIGH 20
//#define TVISIBLE 30

void notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    unsigned int rb;
    unsigned int rc;

    //display control,
    //mode 0
    //enable BG0
    PUT16(DISPCNT,0x0100);
    //BG0 control
    //256 color palette
    //tiles defined at 0x60000000
    //screen at 0x60008000
    PUT16( BG0CNT,0x1080);
    //setup the first 8 colors
    PUT16(PMEM+0x0,0x0000); //BLACK
    PUT16(PMEM+0x2,0x001F); //RED
    PUT16(PMEM+0x4,0x03E0); //GREEN
    PUT16(PMEM+0x6,0x03FF); //GREEN+RED
    PUT16(PMEM+0x8,0x7C00); //BLUE
    PUT16(PMEM+0xA,0x7C1F); //BLUE+RED
    PUT16(PMEM+0xC,0x7FE0); //BLUE+GREEN
    PUT16(PMEM+0xE,0x7FFF); //BLUE+GREEN+RED (WHITE)
    // Let's make a few tiles 64 bytes per tile.
    ra=TMEM;
    PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00000000); ra+=4;

    PUT32(ra,0x01010000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x01010000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x01010000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x01010000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x01010000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x01010000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x01010000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x01010000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00010001); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00010001); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x01000100); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x01000100); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00010001); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00010001); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x01000100); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x01000100); ra+=4;

    PUT32(ra,0x02020000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x02020000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x02020000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x02020000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x02020000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x02020000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x02020000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x02020000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00020002); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00020002); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x02000200); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x02000200); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00020002); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00020002); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x02000200); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x02000200); ra+=4;

    PUT32(ra,0x03030000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x03030000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x03030000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x03030000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x03030000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x03030000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x03030000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x03030000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00030003); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00030003); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x03000300); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x03000300); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00030003); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00030003); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x03000300); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x03000300); ra+=4;

    PUT32(ra,0x04040000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x04040000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x04040000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x04040000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x04040000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x04040000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x04040000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x04040000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00040004); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00040004); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x04000400); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x04000400); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00040004); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00040004); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x04000400); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x04000400); ra+=4;

    PUT32(ra,0x05050000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x05050000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x05050000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x05050000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x05050000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x05050000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x05050000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x05050000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00050005); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00050005); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x05000500); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x05000500); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00050005); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00050005); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x05000500); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x05000500); ra+=4;

    PUT32(ra,0x06060000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x06060000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x06060000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x06060000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x06060000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x06060000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x06060000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x06060000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00060006); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00060006); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x06000600); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x06000600); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00060006); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00060006); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x06000600); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x06000600); ra+=4;

    PUT32(ra,0x07070000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x07070000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x07070000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x07070000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x07070000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x07070000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x07070000); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x07070000); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00070007); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00070007); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x07000700); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x07000700); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x00070007); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x00070007); ra+=4;
    PUT32(ra,0x07000700); ra+=4; PUT32(ra,0x07000700); ra+=4;

    //make screen black/clear screen
    ra=VMEM;
    for(rb=0;rb<(32*20);rb++)
    {
        PUT16(ra,0x0000);
        ra+=2;
    }
    //put some tiles on the screen
    ra=VMEM;
    for(rc=0,rb=0;rb<(32*10);rb++,rc++)
    {
        rc&=7;
        if(rc==0) rc=1;
        PUT16(ra,rc);
        ra+=2;
    }
}
```

memmap

```
MEMORY
{
   ewram : ORIGIN = 0x02000000, LENGTH = 256K
}
SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > ewram
}
```

rommap

```
MEMORY
{
    rom  : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 32K
}
SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
}
```

build

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings  startup.s -o startup.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=arm7tdmi -Wall -Werror -O2 -ffreestanding  notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -T rommap startup.o notmain.o -o gbarom.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D gbarom.elf > gbarom.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy gbarom.elf -O binary notmain.gba
arm-none-eabi-ld -T memmap startup.o notmain.o -o notmain.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.elf -O binary notmain.mb
```

Now vba lets you run multiboot files as well as gba files

```
vba notmain.mb

vba motmain.gba
```

One uses EWRAM the other the GAME ROM.

You do not have to use both a MEMORY and SECTIONS in the linker script, can hard code addresses in the sections but I recommend memory being there as well.  I recommend against using (rwx) stuff, YMMV.

```
MEMORY
{
    rom  : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 32K
}
SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
}
```

The name rom does not matter - you could call it pickle and it will be fine. It is just a name that you use to connect a memory range definition to one or more sections.  .text* inside is all the stuff in the object(s) that start with .text (.text is the instructions). The *() outside that means all objects that are fed through the linker you could specify specific objects for each entry to have finer control (beware the linker script language is not as nice and perfect as you expect, sometimes calling out objects does not work the way you would think).

Then the .text up front is so the output binary uses that name, you could call that .baseball and it would work just fine just tools that you feed that file would not know what to do so just using .text is a good idea.

You add more things like this

```
MEMORY
{
   ewram : ORIGIN = 0x02000000, LENGTH = 256K
}
SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > ewram
   .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ewram
   .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ewram
   .data : { *(.data*) } > ewram
}
```

and it will process those in order in that the .text stuff goes in the output first then .rodata then .bss and last .data. Also note that since no files or objects are called out here the command line drives the order of things as well.

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -T memmap startup.o notmain.o -o notmain.elf
```

we need the entry point code to be first so that file goes first on the command line (easier than complicating it with made up section names, etc).

Note as soon as you build and before you try commit something to a flash

Look at the disassembly:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

02000000 <rom_start>:
 2000000:   ea00002e    b   20000c0 <ram_start>
    ...

020000c0 <ram_start>:
 20000c0:   ea000006    b   20000e0 <_start>
    ...

020000e0 <_start>:
 20000e0:   e59fd024    ldr sp, [pc, #36]   ; 200010c <GET32+0x8>
 20000e4:   eb000009    bl  2000110 <notmain>

020000e8 <hang>:
 20000e8:   eafffffe    b   20000e8 <hang>
```

If you swap the files on the command line

```
Disassembly of section .text:

02000000 <notmain>:
 2000000:   e92d4070    push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
 2000004:   e3a01c01    mov r1, #256    ; 0x100
 2000008:   e3a00301    mov r0, #67108864   ; 0x4000000
 200000c:   eb00028f    bl  2000a50 <PUT16>
 2000010:   e3a01d42    mov r1, #4224   ; 0x1080
 2000014:   e59f06bc    ldr r0, [pc, #1724] ; 20006d8 <notmai
```

game over, that is going to just crash. certainly won't run like you hope/expect (you might get lucky sometimes, but in general this is a fail).

I left room in the bootstrap for logo data and such to get it to work as a real rom for mgba or a real gba with the right cartridge (some have a menu and you do not have to have the cartridge header right).  At the multiboot level you do not need to have all of that space in there just start with the bootstrap.

You could get by with `-Ttext=0x08000000` as a quick and dirty hack, but with gnu ld that still uses a default linker script that is built into the toolchain you are using, and you are just tweaking that section type.  And you start to get into strange things if you push that with more complicated stuff.  So you can see how trivial it is to use a linker script, they do not have to be complicated.  So many people tend to grossly over complicate, and to be honest the gnu linker script language can be painful as it does not always work in a sane and consistent manner.  I prefer to do most of the work elsewhere and not in the linker script.

Comment: I'll give this a shot later, I actually was thinking about this the other day and I realized I might be able to just compile it, and then in an asm file do ```.org 0x08000000 .incbin "mygame.gba"```